# Pure braid group, stabilizer

Tags: group-theory, homotopy-theory, knot-theory

From group theory we know that a homomorphism $\phi: G  \to \operatorname{Sym}(S)$, where S is a set, then $\operatorname{Sym}(S) \cong \Sigma_n $. Its kernel is given as $\bigcap_{s \in S}G_s$, which is the intersection of all the stabilizer subgroups of $G$.

Now, the pure braid group $P_n$ is defined as the kernel of the map $\phi: B_n \to \Sigma_n$.
Is it fair to say, that the pure braid group is such an intersection?

Comment: Can you define $B_n$?

Comment: $B_n$ is the braid group. If $C_n$ is the space of unordered n -tuples of distinct points in the complex plane, then the braid group $B_n$ is the fundamental group of $C_n$. Details e.g. here: http://planetmath.org/BraidGroup.html

Comment: Your first paragraph is hard to read, I cannot tell what is the hypothesis and what is the conclusion. Is it supposed to say "if $\phi : G \to Sym(S)$ is a homomorphism, where $S$ is a set of cardinality $n$ and $Sym(S) \approx \sigma_n$, then the kernel of $\phi$ is given as $\bigcap_{s \in S} G_s$''?

Comment: Yes. The first paragraph is correctly rephrased like this. Sorry, if I didnt make it clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming my comment is correct, there is no restriction in the hypothesis on the group $G$. The statement is true for any $G$ at all. In particular it is true for $G=B_n$.

Comment: Right. So it was obvious. I didn't read it anywhere in this manner and I guess that was due to your point. Thanks.